# Can we concatenate property variable of class..?

Tags: php, oop

**How Can Print property variable with the help of object of class**

*My simple Class*

```
class claculation{

 #---Properties-----#   

public $a;
public $b;
public $c;

 #---Methods-----#

    function sum(){
        
        $this->c=$this->a+$this->b;
        return $this->c;
    }
    
    function sub(){
        $this->c=$this->a-$this->b;
        return $this->c;
    }
    
    function mul(){
        $this->c=$this->a*$this->b;
        return $this->c;
    }
}
```

*Create Object*

```
$obj1= new claculation();
echo "Sum value of C1=";
echo $obj1->a=10;
echo "+";
echo $obj1->b=20;
echo "=";
echo $obj1->sum();
echo "<hr>";
```

I'm sorry in advance if my code makes you laugh. but I want to learn without worry.

I just did this code to get output like this

> Sum value of C1=10+20=30

So the purpose of my question is Is there any advanced way or anyone that can simplify my code to help me get the output I want...?

Comment: So, let me get this straight, you currently get the expected outcome, but would like to know if there's a better ('advanced') way, a way to simplify your code? If you'd like a review of working code, you may consider posting on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - do first read their How to Ask.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, NO ONE could laugh at you if you ask any question, they must laugh at those ones who don't ask and think they are perfect.
If you wanna be a pro (or semi-pro!) you must try to say a poem with the words of codes! your poem must be short, clean, loud, beautiful, smooth, sharp, and effective.

Let start from the end:
can anyone enjoy from doing an summation like it :

```
$obj1= new claculation();
$obj1->a=10;
$obj1->b=10;
$obj1->sum();
```

or they prefer to do this like below? :

```
$obj1= new claculation();
$obj1->sum(10, 20) ;
```

what if they want to add another digits? :

```
$obj1= new claculation();
$obj1->sum(10, 20, 30, ...) ;
```

is there necessary to create an object for such a calculation or we can do it such as:

```
/Claculation::sum(10, 20, 30, ...) ;
```

if we want to create our object isn't it better if users can chain these operators?

```
$obj1->sum(10, 20, 30)->sub(5)->mul(8)->result();
```

what about the priorities? we know that every mathematical equation follows an operand priority (which parentheses have the highest and then / and *, then + and - and etc.), can we achieve this goal by decorating our code?

```
$obj1 = new sum(new sub( new mul(5 , 7) , 5), new sub(5 , 7));
```

is there necessary requirement to create a new object at all?

```
$calculator::exec(new sum(new sub( new mul(5 , 7) , 5), new sub(5 , 7)));
```

---

all of these (and many many other) implementations are your choice and foreach(implementations as a choice) { have its advantages and disadvantages}.

just keep in mind that for such a problem read and/or use these parameters

- design patterns (select best matches especially decorative design pattern)
- exception handlings (negative radical or division by zero or ...)
- type conversion (define your desire precision)
- type hints (speed and readability)
- clean code (depend on your implementation be careful about DRY-GRASP-SOLID-PSA-etc. -especially PSA in yours ! -remove empty lines -create spaces -...)
- avoid unnecessary assignment (ex : $this->c in your code)
- lets life be easier by using splash operator
- etc.

just keep in your mind that nobody is perfect and there is always a better implementation

> in the end it doesn't even matter (LP !)

the only thing is matters are progressing and it will happen till the end of your professional life.